# HTTP request from Jira to Logic App not working, but same json from Postman work

Tags: json, azure, postman, jira, azure-logic-apps

I`m trying to build a Logic app on Azure which will receive JSON from Jira and do some magic on the Azure side. I created a button in Jira flow, which will trigger a webhook to Azure App Logic address. In App Logic I had a step called "When HTTP trigger is received". For schema creation I used the JSON from Jira, so the schema should be okay.

The problem is working with the input. In raw file I can see whole JSON with all details and properties, but it's not divided in to variables automatically.

[Step output directly from JIRA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPzw.png)
[Output from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTQCY.png)

The headers are more or less the same, so that shouldn't be a problem. Without this output I can't work with variables from JSON correctly, because when I will use variables name from Dynamic Menu it will be null (or "")

Comment: Can you please share the sample json and required output details?

Comment: Could you please try to transmit a simpler json data to the trigger and use a simpler schema to test if it works well ?